# FFplay doesn't include the `Authorization` header

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to use [RTSP basic authentication](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2617#section-2) with FFplay. Here's the command:

```
$ ffplay rtsp://admin:123@localhost
```

I expect that FFplay includes the `Authorization: Basic ...` header, but it doesn't (I've observed it with Wireshark). How can I use RTSP basic authentication with FFplay? Google suggests using the aforementioned command but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the thing is that my RTSP server didn't include the `realm="..."` value in the `WWW-Authenticate` header value.

This didn't work:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
```

This worked:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="WallyWorld"
```